New NIC with public IP has no internet connection, while existing NIC works fine
I'm experiencing an issue with a newly added network interface (NIC) on my Azure VM. While the existing NIC works perfectly, the new one fails to connect to the internet. Here are the details:
Current Setup:

VM created with 'Basic SKU dynamic' network configuration

Existing NIC has multiple public IPs (Basic SKU, dynamic) and works fine

Can successfully use curl --interface <existing interface ipv4 address> http://example.com


Problem:

Added a new NIC with a new public IP to the VM
(eth1 is a newly added nic.)
azureuser@instanceXX:~$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:45:bd:48:e7:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.5/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
 # ~~~~skipping the middle~~~~ 
    inet6 fe80::6245:bdff:fe48:e7f1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:1e:52:2b:a9:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.104/24 metric 200 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7e1e:52ff:fe2b:a9ff/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enP12745s1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master eth0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:45:bd:48:e7:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enP12745p0s2
    inet6 fe80::6245:bdff:fe48:e7f1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Looking at # route -n I get this output:
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     200    0        0 eth1
10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
168.63.129.16   10.0.0.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0
168.63.129.16   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    200    0        0 eth1
169.254.169.254 10.0.0.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0


Both Primary and Secondary type IPs on the new NIC fail to connect:
azureuser@instanceXX:~$ curl --interface 10.0.0.104 http://example.com
curl: (28) Failed to connect to example.com port 80 after 134224 ms: Connection timed out



Existing NIC and its IPs still work correctly

Both NICs share the same Network Security Group (NSG), which hasn't been modified since VM creation


Expected Behavior: Two NICs, each with 225 public IPs (Basic SKU, dynamic), all functioning normally.
Additional Notes:

Not using Standard SKU due to cost constraints

NSG settings are default from initial VM creation


Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can suggest a solution to get the new NIC working with internet connectivity? Any insights would be greatly appreciated...!!!
Attempted Solutions:

Used Azure's Connection troubleshoot and Support + troubleshooting tools (no resolution)

Tried creating IPs with different SKUs, but VM failed to boot due to SKU mismatch

Created a new VM and replicated the setup, but encountered the same issue



Solved : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59112745/access-internet-with-second-or-multiple-nic-in-azure

To address the issue of a newly added network interface on your Azure VM not being able to connect to the internet while the existing NIC works fine, follow these steps-
Create a Virtual Network and Subnet
az network vnet create \
  --resource-group arkorg \
  --name myVNet \
  --address-prefix 10.0.0.0/16 \
  --subnet-name mySubnet \
  --subnet-prefix 10.0.0.0/24


Create a Network Security Group (NSG)
az network nsg create \
  --resource-group arkorg \
  --name myNSG


Add Inbound Rules to the NSG for HTTP and SSH
az network nsg rule create \
  --resource-group arkorg \
  --nsg-name myNSG \
  --name AllowInternetInBound \
  --priority 1000 \
  --direction Inbound \
  --access Allow \
  --protocol Tcp \
  --destination-port-range 80 \
  --source-address-prefix Internet \
  --destination-address-prefix '*'

az network nsg rule create \
  --resource-group arkorg \
  --nsg-name myNSG \
  --name AllowSSH \
  --priority 1100 \
  --direction Inbound \
  --access Allow \
  --protocol Tcp \
  --destination-port-range 22 \
  --source-address-prefix Internet \
  --destination-address-prefix '*'



Create Public IP Addresses for the NICs
az network public-ip create \
  --resource-group arkorg \
  --name myExistingPublicIP \
  --sku Basic \
  --allocation-method Dynamic

az network public-ip create \
  --resource-group arkorg \
  --name myNewPublicIP \
  --sku Basic \
  --allocation-method Dynamic



Create Network Interfaces and Associate Them with Public IPs
az network nic create \
  --resource-group arkorg \
  --name myExistingNIC \
  --vnet-name myVNet \
  --subnet mySubnet \
  --network-security-group myNSG \
  --public-ip-address myExistingPublicIP

az network nic create \
  --resource-group arkorg \
  --name myNewNIC \
  --vnet-name myVNet \
  --subnet mySubnet \
  --network-security-group myNSG \
  --public-ip-address myNewPublicIP



Create a VM with your existing NIC
az vm create \
  --resource-group arkorg \
  --name myVM \
  --nics myExistingNIC \
  --image Ubuntu2204 \
  --admin-username azureuser \
  --generate-ssh-keys


Now comes your main problem that is update the VM with new IP and it should be able to connect to the net.
So first deallocate the old one
az vm deallocate \
  --resource-group arkorg \
  --name myVM


Followed by adding of your new NIC and restarting the VM
az vm nic add \
  --resource-group arkorg \
  --vm-name myVM \
  --nics myNewNIC

az vm start \
  --resource-group arkorg \
  --name myVM



If done till here, then you're sorted. Now you just have to SSH into the VM using the public IP of the existing NIC
ssh azureuser@<existing-public-ip>

Run the following commands to set up source-based routing:
sudo su
echo "200 eth0" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
echo "201 eth1" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add from 10.0.0.4/32 table eth0
ip rule add from 10.0.0.5/32 table eth1
ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0 src 10.0.0.4 table eth0
ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 table eth0
ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 dev eth1 src 10.0.0.5 table eth1
ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1 table eth1


Verify the routing rules
ip rule show
ip route show table eth0
ip route show table eth1


Test Connectivity
curl --interface 10.0.0.4 http://example.com
curl --interface 10.0.0.5 http://example.com



Thank you so much for your detailed and helpful answer! I really appreciate the time and effort you put into explaining this. Your solution worked perfectly and helped me understand the concept better. Microsoft should pay you...! :)
